# how to sort stream from ObjectBox and difference .watch() vs .stream()

Tags: flutter, stream, objectbox

I am wondering hot to get a stream sorted.

This is my unsorted stream:

```dart
Stream<List<User> userStream = userBox.query()
  .watch(triggerImmediately: true).map((query) 
  => query.find();
```

Adding `..order()` after `query()` or also after `map((query) query` adds in pre-compile errors.

```dart
Stream<List<User> userStream = userBox.query()
  ..order(User_.date)
  .watch(triggerImmediately: true).map((query) 
  => query.find();
```

Also - what is the difference of the above notation to

```dart
Query<User> query = userBox.query().build();
Stream<User stream = query.stream();
await stream.forEach((User user) => print(user));
query.close();
```

Has a `stream()` method be implemented in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
userBox.query().order(User_.date).watch(triggerImmediately: true)
```

should work.

`stream()` returns the results of the query once, `watch()` observes the associated Box and sends a Query whenever there are changes.

Source: [ObjectBox Dart API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/objectbox/latest/objectbox/objectbox-library.html)